# Proof involving power sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let $A$ be a random set in the universal set $U$. $\mathbb{P}(A)$ is the powerset of $A$. Remember that $\mathbb{P}(A)$ is a set in the universal set $\mathbb{P}(U)$. Prove that $\mathbb{P}(A^c) \subseteq (\mathbb{P}(A))^c \cup \{\} $.

All I have is: $X \in \mathbb{P}(A^c) \implies X \in \mathbb{P}(A^c) \cap \mathbb{P}(U)  \implies X \in (\mathbb{P}(A))^c \implies X \in (\mathbb{P}(A))^c \cup \{\}  $.

But I'm pretty sure this is incorrect. What do we have to do here? The complements confuse me, $\mathbb{P}(A))^c$ and $\mathbb{P}(A^c)$, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb P(A^c)$ is the family of all subsets of $A^c$; the subsets of $A^c$ are precisely the subsets of $U$ that are disjoint from $A$. That is, $\Bbb P(A^c)=\{X\subseteq U:X\cap A=\varnothing\}$. I prefer to write these things in terms of set differences: $A^c=U\setminus A$, so $\Bbb P(A^c)=\Bbb P(U\setminus A)$, the family of all subsets of $U\setminus A$. These are clearly the subsets of $U$ that don’t intersect $A$.

$(\Bbb P(A))^c$, on the other hand, is the complement of $\Bbb P(A)$ in $\Bbb P(U)$: it’s the family of all subsets of $U$ that are *not* subsets of $A$. In terms of set differences, $(\Bbb P(A))^c=\Bbb P(U)\setminus\Bbb P(A)$; this is pretty easily seen to be the collection of subsets of $U$ that are not subsets of $A$.

HINT: Now suppose that $X\in\Bbb P(A^c)$; then as we saw in the first paragraph, $X\cap A=\varnothing$. You want to show that either $X=\varnothing$, or $X\in(\Bbb P(A))^c=\Bbb P(U)\setminus\Bbb P(A)$. If $X=\varnothing$, there’s nothing to prove. Suppose that $X\ne\varnothing$; if $X\cap A=\varnothing$, can $X$ be a subset of $A$?

Comment: I understand how to prove it now thanks to the hint, but I still have trouble grasping the difference between $\mathbb{P}(A^c)$ and $(\mathbb{P}(A))^c$. I understand your description of the two, but I don't see how they aren't equal to each other.

Comment: @YakSalTafri: Let’s look at a simple example: $U=\{0,1\}$ and $A=\{0\}$. Now $A^c=\{1\}$, so $\Bbb P(A^c)=\{\varnothing,\{1\}\}$. $\Bbb P(A)=\{\varnothing,\{0\}\}$, and $$\Bbb P(U)=\big\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\big\}\;,$$ so $$(\Bbb P(A))^c=\big\{\{1\},\{0,1\}\big\}\;.$$ As you can see, the two sets are quite different: they both contain $\{1\}$, but only one contains $\varnothing$, and only one contains $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you can basically say that since $X$ is not a subset of $A$ (disregarding the possibility that $X$ is the empty set), $X$ is not an element of $\mathbb{P}(A)$, and thus $X$ is an element of ($\mathbb{P}(A))^c$.

Comment: @YakSalTafri: Yes, exactly. All of the sets in question are subsets of $U$, and by definition $(\Bbb P(A))^c$ contains the ones that are *not* elements of $\Bbb P(A)$, i.e., are not subsets of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $B \subseteq A^c$ and $B \neq \emptyset$.   Then there's an $x \in B$, and $x \notin A$, so $B \not\subset A$, so $B \in \mathbb{P}(A)^c$